# How to implement the equivalent for jQuery .map() in plain JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working to convert my code into plain JS, it's really hard. I need a function to get the real scroll container and the one I have goes like this, using `.map()`.

```js
//get true container for scroll events
function getScrollContainer(c) {
 return $(c).map(function() {
  var cnt = this,
   isWin = !cnt.nodeName || $.inArray( cnt.nodeName.toLowerCase(), ['iframe','#document','html','body'] ) != -1;
   if (!isWin) return cnt;

  var doc = (cnt.contentWindow || cnt).document || cnt.ownerDocument || cnt;

  return /webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || doc.compatMode == 'BackCompat' ?
   doc.body :
   doc.documentElement;
    });
}
console.log(getScrollContainer(window));
```

is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this. Use the native `.map` method, and include a polyfill: `[1,2,3].map(function (i) { return i * 2 }); // => [2, 4, 6]`

Comment: Your code sample seems nice and clean. Do you have one I can understand & adapt / use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map is just a fancy way to say "apply this function to every element in the list" so it could be easily implemented in a for loop.

Something like this: (Not perfect or tested, but should give you an idea)

```
    function getScrollContainer(c) {
        c = Object.prototype.toString.call( c ) === '[object Array] ? c : [c];
        for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            var cnt = c[i],
                isWin = !cnt.nodeName || indexOf(cnt.nodeName.toLowerCase(), ['iframe','#document','html','body'] ) != -1;
                if (!isWin) return cnt;

            var doc = (cnt.contentWindow || cnt).document || cnt.ownerDocument || cnt;

            return /webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || doc.compatMode == 'BackCompat' ?
                doc.body :
                doc.documentElement;
        }                   
    }
```

Comment: Tested your code as well, it in the for statement it sais i is not defined.

Comment: Looks like the code was already using something called I. Change the loop variable to j or something else.

Comment: Also not defined. Seems my <code>function getScrollContainer(c) {}</code> would need this i/j property. I already triend and it's messy.

Comment: Sorry apparently I made a typo. You will want for(var j = 0; to define it as part of the loop

Comment: Thanks so much, I think your answer kicked me. I am getting no error and works fine. I need to change it a bit so I can check if c is an array, if not make it array.

Comment: Found it, just before your for I made <code>c = Object.prototype.toString.call( c ) === '[object Array]' ? c : [c];</code> and it's great.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code that you have posted you don't need to use the `map` method. Your function accepts just one parameter so you can just remove the `var cnt = this,` line and use the `c` parameter. Now your function instead of returning a jQuery-wrapped array with `length` of 1, returns a [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) object.

If you want to pass an array to the function you can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```
function getScrollContainer(c) {
    return c.map(function(value, index, arr) {
        // ...
    });
}

console.log(getScrollConainer([window, 'foo']));
```

And for replacing the jQuery `$.inArray` utility function you can use the [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexof) method:

```
['iframe','#document','html','body'].indexOf(cnt.nodeName.toLowerCase()) != -1
```

Note that IE8 and below do no support the Array `map` and `indexOf` methods. If you want to support those browsers you can use a polyfill. MDN suggests [this polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexof#Polyfill) for `Array.prototype.indexOf`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I need a function that acts just like the one presented, please edit your answer so I can have a fully working function, with IE8 support.

Answer (score 1):

While the answers above will work in your case, they will not in every case. jQuery's map creates a new array and returns that array after applying the function to every item in the array.

the prototype map function does not create a new array and instead simply applies the function to each item.

this sometime will produce the same result and others will produce different results.

You will get the same result for this example:

```
$.map([1,2,3], function(i){ return i+1; });
 => [2,3,4]

[1,2,3].map(function(i){ return i+1; });
 => [2,3,4]
```

However the below example will provide a different result:

```
$.map([1,2,3], function(i){ if(i > 1){ return i; } });
 => [2,3]

[1,2,3].map(function(i){ if(i > 1){ return i; } });
 => [undefined,2,3]
```

Comment: good to know this! But what is the way to fix this in plain JS?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, you can use if statements inside .map() if you create a new function for the Array prototype:

```
Array.prototype.custom_Map = function(x) {
arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
var _this = (x(this[i], i, this));
if(_this !== null) {
    arr.push(_this);
    return arr;
    };
```

You can use it the following way:

`x.custom_Map(function(a){ if(a>0) {return true;}});`